# H2O document question for stopping_tolerance, score_each_iteration, score_tree_interval, etc

Tags: h2o

I have the following questions that still confused me after I read the h2o document. Can someone provide some explanation for me

1. For the stopping_tolerance = 0.001, let's use AUC for example, current AUC is 0.8. Does that mean the AUC need to increase 0.8 + 0.001 or need to increase 0.8*(1+0.1%)?
2. score_each_iteration, in H2O document
   (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/score_each_iteration.html) it just say "iteration". But what exactly is the definition for each
   "iteration", is that each tree or each grid search or each K folder
   cross validation or something else?
3. Can I define score_tree_interval and set score_each_iteration = True
   at the same time or I can only use one of them to make the grid
   search repeatable?
4. Is there any difference to put 'stopping_metric',
   'stopping_tolerance', 'stopping_rounds' in
   H2OGradientBoostingEstimator vs in search_criteria of H2OGridSearch?
   I found put in H2OGradientBoostingEstimator will make the code run
   much faster when I test it in Spark environment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. 0.001 is the same as 0.1%, for AUC since bigger is better, you will want to see an increase of at least .001 after a specified number of scoring rounds.
2. You have linked to a portion of the documentation that is specific to the algorithms listed in `Available in` at the top of the page. So let's stick to answering this question with respect to individual models and not grid search. If you want to see what is being scored at each iteration take a look at your model results in Flow or use my_model.plot() (for the python api) to see what is getting scored at each iteration. For GBM and DRF this will be ntrees, but since different algorithms will have different aspects that change the word iteration is used since it is more generic.
3. Did you test this out? what did you find when you did this? Take a look at the scoring history plot in flow and notice what happens when you set both score_tree_interval and score_each_iteration = True versus when you only set score_tree_interval (I would recommend trying to understand these parameters at the individual model level before you use grid search).
4. yes, in once case you are specifying early stopping as you build an individual model in the case of grid search you are indicating whether on not to build more models.

Comment: for question 1, if current AUC is 0.8, stopping_tolerance = 0.001 requires AUC increase to 0.8*(1+0.1%) instead of 0.8 + 0.001?

Comment: for question 3, I tested using random forest, I found a) if I specify score_each_iteration = True, it will run faster. b) the result of specify score_each_iteration is the same as specify both but different from specify only score_tree_interval = 5. c) When I run grid search I need to specify both score_each_iteration = True and set score_tree_interval = 5 to make it repeatable. I don't know why